# How to run sahi script on a new browser after opening a new browser through Sahi script

Tags: testing, automated-tests, sahi

I am able to open firefox browser from a browser using sahi script like:

```
var $path = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

//var $name = "firefox";

var $browseroption = " -profile D:\\sahi_pro_V4.0\\userdata\\browser\\ff\\profiles\\sahi1 -no-remote";

_execute($path + $browseroption);
```

But, when i give _navigateTo after this, it is executed in the first browser itself. Is it possible to run it in the newly opened firefox browser?

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, but one of the following two APIs could be useful depending on your test requirement: [_launchNewBrowser](http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/multiple-browsers.html#_launchNewBrowser) and [_openBrowser](http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/action-apis.html#_openBrowser).